# If $S_i$ are countable sets, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to show that a countable union of countable set is countable.

**proof**

Let $\{S_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ a collection of countable sets. Let denote
$$S_i=\{x_j^i\}_{j=1}^\infty .$$

Then $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n=\{\{x_j^i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$$
is a sequence of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$, therefore $$f:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\longrightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty  S_i$$ define by $$f(i,j)=x_j^i$$ is surjective, and thus $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is countable.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Technically, you should be focusing on injections, not surjections. So you want $f$ to be an injection from $\bigcup S_i$ to $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$, with an appropriate reversal of the definition. This is just because that's the convension on comparing cardinalities. The two approaches are not equivalent unless you assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Clayton : Yes, I correct it. **arthur** You right. But I can suppose all $x_{i}^j$, therefore I would have a bijection, no ?

Comment: Yes, if all the $S_i$ are infinite, and there are infinitely many of them, then you have a bijection defined the natural way. If not, the natural definition of $f$ will only give an injection, which is still enough.

Comment: If you try to define an injection $f : \cup S_i \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ in the obvious way - $f(x_i^j) = (i,j)$ - you have to take care that $f$ is well-defined, since $x_{i}^j$ may not describe a unique member of the union.